# laravel migrate

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un proble al migrar las tablas en mi base de datos, es algo simple

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen se ve que agrego un nuevo campo (nombre) pero al momento de migrar me dice que no hay nada que migrar, pero si hago un rollback y despues un migrate ahi si agarra, pero lo que eso hace es borrarme los datos que tenia la tabla,
hay alguna forma de agregar nuevos campos sin eliminar mis datos?

Comment: Tienes que acceder a la tabla migrations y ver si ya existe la migracion que ya ejecutaste, por esa razon te indica que no hay migraciones a realizar porque seguramente ya este almacenada esa migracion. Tambien te adjunto un enlace de la documentación de Laravel sobre las migraciones. Recuerda elegir la versión que estés utlizando.  Debes ejecutar una migracion diferente por nuevo campo añadido. [enlace] https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations [enlace]

Answer (score 1):

Si originalmente hiciste una migración para crear la tabla

```
Schema::create('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id();
   $table->timestamps();
 });
```

Al ejecutarla se guardó un registro en la BBDD asociado al nombre del archivo de la migración, señalando "esta migración ya se corrió". Artisan mira ese registro y pasa por alto cualquier modificación a los archivos asociados.

Si tú haces un rollback ese registro se elimina y ahora Artisan sí toma en cuenta el archivo. Sin embargo editar migraciones existentes es una mala práctica: generas inconsistencias para las migraciones siguientes. Excepcionalmente, cuando se trata de la migración más reciente y no se ha pasado a producción, en realidad no tiene consecuencias.

Como sea: si quieres añadir un campo a la tabla no sacas nada editando el archivo de migración. Tienes que crear otra migración específica para el nuevo campo

```
 php artisan make:migration add_nombre_to_clientes_table --table=clientes
```

Y en ella pondrías:

```
    Schema::table('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('nombre');
    });
```

Fíjate que la primera usa el método `Schema::create` mientras que la nueva usa `Schema::table`. De paso, el método `down` de la primera consiste en un DROP de la tabla completa. En el  `down` de la segunda migración pondrías, en cambio:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('nombre');
    });
}
```

#### Bonus Track

La idea es que cuando se integra un colaborador a tu equipo pueda correr `artisan migrate` de un viaje y quedar con tu mismo schema.

Si acaso alguien editó una migración ya ejecutada, por ejemplo añadiendo el campo `nombre` al crear la tabla, la nueva migración se volvería inconsistente y arrojaría error.

Cuando eso pasa se puede usar una comprobación y añadir el campo sólo si no existe:

```
    Schema::table('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        if (!Schema::hasColumn($table->getTable(), 'nombre')) {
            $table->string('nombre');
        }
    });
```